# Shortcuts (hotkeys) in WordPress HTML editor

Tags: wordpress

Is it possible to use editor shortcuts (hotkeys) in WordPress HTML editor?
In Visual editor everything works fine (Ctrl-B for "bold" e.g.), but in HTML editor no shortcut work.

Is it possible/necessary to configure that somewhere???

Answer (score 0):

WordPress html editor is a simple text editor and only few keyboard shortcuts are available. They are,

- Ctrl + c = Copy
- Ctrl + v = Paste
- Ctrl + x = Cut
- Ctrl + z = Undo
- Ctrl+ y = Redo
- Ctrl + p = Print

It is possible to add more shortcuts for the html editor. You can [refer this](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/74568/create-keyboard-shortcuts-for-html-mode) for doing that.

Bonus: If you want to access the complete list of WordPress keyboard shortcuts from your browser, simply [install this extension](https://www.techwyse.com/wordpress-shortcuts/) to Google chrome.